# H-bridge - MOSFET driver

Tags: voltage, mosfet, capacitor, pwm, mosfet-driver

I am trying to implement an H-bridge with the [MIC5021](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/20005677A.pdf) for the high side of both legs and an [MIC5020](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mic5020.pdf) for the low side of both legs.

I have used the MIC5020 in other designs and it seems to be working great. This is the first time I have used the MIC5021 and I am not getting the boost voltage needed to fully turn on the high side MOSFET.

When the train of pulses starts, I see one large pulse at close to the correct voltage and over the next few pulses (3-4) it diminishes to system voltage (in this case 24 V). Initially I had a 0.1 μF capacitor which I later realized was way too big and possibly damaging the MIC5021. I downsized this to 0.01 μF and I still am seeing similar results. I have ordered 2.7 nF capacitors to try next and I am currently waiting for them to arrive.

In the datasheet for the MIC5021 I see the boost capacitor tied to system voltage in one diagram and the source of the MOSFET being driven in another. Which diagram is correct/better? Is there an advantage of one configuration over the other? Ultimately I need to get the boost capacitor generating the proper voltage to drive the MOSFET fully ON as it is not doing it right now. What can I do to address this?

In the attached image the system voltage is 24 V. Here are the signals:

Yellow: High-side signal from controller
Blue: Low-side signal from controller
Red: @ Low-side gate
Green: @ High-side gate

[image]

Comment: What an oddball chip. I wonder who actually uses it. I can't say I understand why the difference in how Cboost is wired, or why it needs to be such small values. They don't show any detail on the "charge pump". What's wrong with a more traditional bootstrap dual driver like IRS2110?

Comment: I was not aware of the IRS part that you mentioned. Could you please let me know your thoughts on my problem? How to address it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the MIC5021 but it sounds like Fig. 6-2 or 6-3 should be equally usable at 24V. If you have set these up correctly and are having problems, I suggest taking measurements of many points in the circuit (including waveforms), and show that as well as your exact schematic and layout.

Comment: Could you tell me which waveforms you require @TimWilliams

Comment: All of them, would be best

Comment: Could you please list the pin names and nodes? I can share?

Comment: @TimWilliams , added the waveform in the question with labels mentioned separately. Can you please help?

Comment: I think I can see what's going on here, but in the future please separate the traces so they can be read individually. At least the inputs could be moved out of the way here. Do you have a schematic? What is the load? What is VDD during this? Vboost?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142445/discussion-between-newbie-and-tim-williams).

Comment: The datasheet tells you clearly about whether to connect the boost cap to VDD or the mosfet source based of what voltage range you expect. Also, what mosfets are you using and have you asked your friends at Microchip for assistance?